# Release two different versions on Testflight

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm in a situation where we wanted to test 2 different versions of the App:
**Version 1.0.0** is going to be released on the App Store and is currently under testing.
**Version 2.0.0** is under testing only.

Let’s say I have released *Version 1.0.0 - Build number* 1 on Testflight.

If I wanted to release a new build for version 1.0.0 it wouldn’t be a problem… I could increase the build number and keep version number unchanged (Like *Version 1.0.0 - Build 2*).

Now, Let’s say that I'm also uploading *Version 2.0.0 - build 3* on testflight. 
Is it true that from now on **I cannot upload other versions that are lower than 2.0.0**?

If I've uploaded version *2.0.0* but Apple rejects my current build for *1.0.0* during the App Store review process… I couldn't send to Apple another build *1.0.0*, the only way to go would be to upload a new build increasing version number to *2.0.0* or greater then?

Am I saying anything wrong?

Comment: So were you able to do that or not?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do any combination you want to make, like after uploading 1.0.1(2) you can upload 1.0.1(1) as well as 1.0.0(5). There is no restriction for uploading lower version or lower build.

Have a look into image and note dates.

[image]

I had uploaded v1.0.3(10000) first(13th Jul) and then uploaded v1.0.2(10200)(on 16th Jul).

Comment: The really revealing sequence is 1.0.3(10300) followed by 1.0.2(10200). This proves that _both_ values can be smaller.

Comment: The initial sentence in this answer is inaccurate. You demonstrate uploading earlier build numbers for other versions, but not within the same version. The order that you have demonstrated works is: 1.0.1(10100) -> 1.0.3(10000) -> 1.0.2(10200) -> 1.0.3(10300). Notice that you cannot upload 1.0.3(10201) now, even though you could upload a 1.0.2(10201) because the build numbers within the version are independent but must be increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Well lets make a little difference between sending the app for App Store review or Test-Flight in here:

1- You uploaded to Test-Flight 1.0.0 build 1 for testing purpose and then you need to send another one for testing purpose, which will be 1.0.0 build 2, you just keep on increasing the build number and not the version.

2- Ones you finished Testing and you want to release the build to the App Store Review lets say you sent version 1.0.0 build 2 for review, Now if apple has accepted the app and its ready for sale or pending developer release, you are forced to adjust the version number for your next release to be 1.0.1 or 1.1.0 and you can reset the build number to start from 1 again, but never version 1.0.0.

You will get an error from Xcode if you tried to upload a version that has been accepted from apple, you will need to increase the version number. always remember that.

Hope this helps u out.

Comment: One important thing to add is that a version string is a string made of individual integers, not a decimal number. The order does not go `"1.1"`, `"1.11"`, `"1.2"`. 11 is bigger than 2. I've been caught out by that one...!

Comment: @matt, Yep that is totally true that one got me too.